# How to integrate RequireJS module into AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, requirejs

I want to integrate RequireJS module into AngularJS application. Below you can see a sample code. How do I load `Module` from `module.js` in my `app.js`?

**Edit:** look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278966/how-to-integrate-requirejs-module-into-angularjs-application#30281340) I posted as an answer myself. Do you have any comments about it?

```js
// module.js
define('Module', [], function() {
  return {
    init: function() {
      console.log("Module created!");
    }
  };
});

// app.js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  // I want Module to be available here
  $scope.data = 'app';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.17/require.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-app="app">
  <div ng-bind="data"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: It does not directly answer your question, but you may find [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres how you can use RequireJS modules and AngularJS modules system together.

I have kept each AngularJS component in a separate require module so you can load it as and when you needed. because of require dependencies, RequireJS will make sure of loading all other angular modules needed in current angular module.

`utils.getDeps` will automatically create angular module dependencies array for current angular module using requireJS dependencies.

```js
define('listModule', ['angular', 'jquery', 'utils', 'service'], function(ng, $, utils){
    var moduleInfo = {
        moduleName: 'listModule',
        deps: utils.getDeps(arguments)
    };
    
    angular.module(moduleInfo.moduleName, moduleInfo.deps)
      .directive('list', function (){
          return {
              restrict: 'E',
              template: '<div> <ul> <li ng-repeat="item in slist"> {{ item.name }} - {{ item.car }} </li> </ul> </div>',
              controller: function($scope, service){
                  $scope.slist = service.getCustomers();
              }
          }
      });
    
    return moduleInfo;
});

define('service', ['angular', 'jquery', 'utils'], function(ng, $, utils){
    var moduleInfo = {
        moduleName: 'serviceModule',
        deps: utils.getDeps(arguments)
    };
    
    angular.module(moduleInfo.moduleName, moduleInfo.deps)
      .service('service', function (){
          this.getCustomers =  function (){
              return [
                  {
                      name: 'Jack',
                      car: 'Audi'
                  },
                  {
                      name: 'Rekha',
                      car: 'Mercedes'
                  }
              ];
          };
      });
    
    return moduleInfo;
});

define('utils', ['jquery'], function($){
    var obj = {};
    obj.getDeps = function(args){
        return  $.map(args, function (e) {
             return e && e.moduleName;
        });
    };
    return obj;
});

require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min',
        'angular': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': { exports: 'angular', deps: [ 'jquery' ] },
        'jquery': { exports: 'jquery' }
    }
});

require(['angular', 'jquery', 'utils', 'listModule', 'service'], function (angular, $, utils) {
    angular.module('mainApp', utils.getDeps(arguments));
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap($('#main'), ['mainApp']);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.17/require.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
    <list></list>
</div>
```

Comment: It is a little over engineered for my case. However I came to a very similar solution.

Comment: @RuslanasBalčiūnas **No**, when you have big applications with so many  components then this suites best. we had more then 300+ components in whole angularjs application. in this example i have used named `define` so you can't see the benefit but in real application each module will be in different file and you can reference them using relative path. 

may be in your case this could be over engineered.

Comment: I have a real application in mind and I want to use only one module. There is no point in rewriting it as an Angular module. It's an audio application.

Comment: if you have one or two module only then i agree that you don't need such architecture.

Comment: It's a good answer. But it's a bit hard to understand at first because it does  not use any of my code in question. Maybe I'll have to agree with you at some point. I still have to think over it.

Comment: @RuslanasBalčiūnas Sure, let me know if you need any help in understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Since app.js is just a javscript file, you could just use

```
require(['Module'], function(Module) {
     Module.init();
})
```

Turn it into a sort of hybrid application?

Answer (score 0):

For now my solution is to bootstrap app manually after required modules are loaded.

```js
// module.js
define('Module', [], function() {
  return {
    init: function(elm, data) {
      elm.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
    }
  };
});

// app.js
// let it be Require app
require(['Module'], function(Module) {
  
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.directive('module', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        data: '=data'
      },
      link: function(scope, elm, attr) {      
        Module.init(elm[0], scope.data);      
      }
    }
  });

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      type: 'block'
    };
  });

  // manlually initialize
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
  });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.17/require.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <module data="data"/>
</body>
```